# django - can i add a method to always get called when a "get" or "filter" is called on a model?

Tags: django

it isn't possible to call a model's methods in a template without making your own template method. Hence, to show, say, the number of upvotes for a comment:

```
comment.rating_set.filter(vote=1).count()
```

each comment, before it is sent to the template, has a rating_set member added to it like so:

```
comment.rating_set = comment.rating_set.filter(vote=1).count()
```

simple enough, however there are several ways for a comment to be retrieved (that is, several methods that are used to get a comment, depending on the situation). The template is constantly used.

For each method, its possible to alter it so instead of:

```
return commentList
```

it reads

```
return addInVotes(commentList)
```

where `addInVotes` is just a simple function that loops through each comment in the list, and then runs the above code to add the rating_count value.

the question here then is this - instead of adding this across all the methods, is it possible to "attach" the code to model.get and model.filter? I'm aware i can extend the Model for the comment  to have a newly defined filter and get, but is there any other way? It seems like the kind of thing dJango would have hidden away somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at the manager object, it was pretty much designed for this exact use case.

Comment: @Elliott hey! put this as an answer and i'll mark you up, this was just what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) object. You can create a subclass of the default manager with additional methods that do common filtering, in one place, instead of in every view.